# How to retrieve dictionary query result and work with it in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to store my result from an SQL query that the result is in the following format in a local variable.

```
key | value
  A | aaa 
  B | bbb 
  C | ccc
```

Is there anything similar that would make possible to working with result by providing the key value?

```
print 'Example: ' + result['A'] + '.' => 'Example: aaa.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Table variable and `DECLARE @tab TABLE([key] VARCHAR(100), [value] VARCHAR(100));SELECT [value] FROM @tab WHERE [key] = 'A'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use table variable  or a temp table

```
create table @tablevar (key varchar(10) , value int)

insert into @tablevar values ('A' , 1) , ('B',2) , ...
```

table variables have hard coded statistics and they suck if you have alot of key/value set in them , so instaed you can use temp table

```
create table #temptable (key varchar(10) , value int)

insert into #temptable values ('A', 1) , ('B',2) , ...
```

Comment: This is good I found information about that. But that's alright, I'll up vote that answer, but is there a way to simplicity that to get value without saving it to temp variable?
 `CREATE TABLE #import_aliases (field_name varchar(36) , alias nvarchar(100))`
 `select field_name, alias INTO #import_aliases from tablexxxx`

 `declare @test nvarchar(100)`
 `select  @test=alias from #import_aliases where field_name = 'A'`
 `print @test`

Comment: that's the only way ;) , unless you make a function/proc and use that function /proc

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept that as the complete answer to my question.

Comment: I've noticed that there is no need to create a table upfront  if you use SELECT INTO statement.
Example: `select id, name INTO #temp_table from table....`

Comment: yes you can , but it's better to create the table upfront , so you can control the datatypes and if you need an index